# Subset to only return complete cases on group basis with multiple rows

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, plyr, tidyr

If I have a data.frame, DF, with 5 variables with varying groups with between 1 and 24 rows - exemplified with this:

```
GROUP_ID    VAR_1    VAR_2    VAR_3    VAR_4    VAR_5
1             2        4        5        6        6
1             3        4        2        3        4
1             4       NA        6        6        3
1             3        2        1        2        4
2             9        8        2        7        1
2             2        3        3        2        6
2             2        5        8        9        2
3             2        1        5        6       NA
3            NA       NA        5        8        9
3             4        2        6        8        7
```

In this, complete case would be defined as groups with has no NA in any of the variables in any of the rows with that respective group_ID. In this example, only GROUP_ID 2 would represent a complete case.

How do I subset the data.frame in such way that it finds the groups with complete cases and return all the rows with that group ID (in this example only returning all the rows for GROUP_ID 2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this. First `group_by` your grouping variable(s), and then use `filter_at` to filter on the variables that you care about complete cases for. Here we use `starts_with` to select all the `VAR` variables (in fact because there are no other columns we could have used `filter_all`). Then we use `all_vars` to wrap the predicate that checks for the values being non-missing. This basically says "for each group, check if `all` the values in each column are nonmissing. Keep the row if this is true for all the columns (`all_vars`)."

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- structure(list(GROUP_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), VAR_1 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 4L), VAR_2 = c(4L, 4L, NA, 2L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, NA, 2L), VAR_3 = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 6L), VAR_4 = c(6L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 8L), VAR_5 = c(6L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 2L, NA, 9L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = list(GROUP_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), VAR_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), VAR_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), VAR_3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), VAR_4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector")), VAR_5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", "collector"))), class = "col_spec"))

tbl %>%
  group_by(GROUP_ID) %>%
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("VAR")), all_vars(all(!is.na(.))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#> # Groups:   GROUP_ID [1]
#>   GROUP_ID VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 VAR_4 VAR_5
#>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1        2     9     8     2     7     1
#> 2        2     2     3     3     2     6
#> 3        2     2     5     8     9     2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: If I have additional variables in the data.frame, but they are to be omitted from this as only VAR_1 to VAR_5 are of interest, do the "all_vars" function apply only to variables specified within filter_at or all variables in data.frame?

Comment: all_vars applies to those selected in vars(). variables not selected will be ignored

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple one-line base R solution -

```
DF[ave(complete.cases(DF), DF$GROUP_ID, FUN = all), ]

  GROUP_ID VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 VAR_4 VAR_5
5        2     9     8     2     7     1
6        2     2     3     3     2     6
7        2     2     5     8     9     2
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach by using `ave` would be

```
df[as.logical(ave(rowSums(is.na(df)), df$GROUP_ID, 
                     FUN = function(x) all(x == 0))), ]

#  GROUP_ID VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 VAR_4 VAR_5
#5        2     9     8     2     7     1
#6        2     2     3     3     2     6
#7        2     2     5     8     9     2
```

We count the number of `NA`s in every row and filter the rows which have 0 `NA`'s for `all` of the row values in each `GROUP_ID`.

---

Or a little more concise which gives the same result

```
df[ave(rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0, df$GROUP_ID, FUN = all), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using the number of `NA` per group (in case it is something you are also interested in).

```
GROUP_ID.NA.COUNT <- tapply(rowSums(is.na(DF[paste("VAR", 1:5, sep = "_")])),
                            DF$GROUP_ID, FUN = sum) # number of NA per group based on values from VAR_1 to VAR_5
DF[DF$GROUP_ID %in% which(GROUP_ID.NA.COUNT == 0), ] # Subset to only return group with 0 NA based on values from VAR_1 to VAR_5

# output
  GROUP_ID VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 VAR_4 VAR_5
5        2     9     8     2     7     1
6        2     2     3     3     2     6
7        2     2     5     8     9     2
```